# 163 A - 400 Hz CT Testing For Aviation Generator Application

Tags: testing, current-transformer, aviation-electronics, ct

What power supply equipment could I use to provide a 400 Hz, 163 A rms supply to support the testing of a wound Current Transformer installed to an aircraft power generator?

The test requirements are as follows:

"The assembly should provide a voltage of 3.45 as measured across a 10 ohm, 3 watt burden resistor, when a single turn primary current of 163amps rms 400Hz is flowing."

Could I down rate all of the test requirements, whilst maintaining the ratio relationship (1:10 for example - 0.345 V with 16.3A @ 400Hz?) to make this a little more achievable?

Answer (score 1):

If you need to test the current transformer at 163 A through the primary hole, then you need to test the current transformer at 163 Ampere turns in the primary.

Doing it at 1/10th of the current assumes something about the linearity of the CT that you are testing. It's a test that will fail if the CT is grossly bad, but it won't test for non-linearities such as saturation which may bite at the top end of the rated current. It's not so much that the primary current that saturates the core (as there's a substantially cancelling secondary current), but the induced voltage. You may well find a core that doesn't saturate at 0.345 V on the secondary does so at 3.45 V, though it shouldn't if it's been designed properly.

As you need a real 163 Ampere turns in the primary to do the test, you could use a multiple turn primary to reduce your current requirement, at the expense of needing more volts. For instance, ten turns threaded through the primary with 16.3 A per turn will give you the same excitation, at the cost of 10x the voltage needed from your test gear.

I would recommend using an audio amplifier, to drive current through a 4 Ω resistor in series with your multiturn primary. Even if you used only 10 turns, 16 A is a rated 250 watts into 4 Ω, not a particularly big amplifier. With more primary turns, you won't need as much rated power, or as physically large 4 Ω resistor.

Answer (score 1):

> *Could I down rate all of the test requirements, whilst maintaining the
> ratio relationship (1:10 for example - 0.345 V with 16.3A @ 400Hz?) to
> make this a little more achievable?*

**A bit of background information**

A tricky area when designing a CT is to make sure that the magnetization current (a necessary small fraction of the overall primary current) doesn't saturate the core at higher levels. If it does (even a little bit), it will erode the CT accuracy and linearity.

**16.3 amps vs 163 amps**

If you want to use 16.3 amps instead of 163 amps (and prove that the core isn't introducing saturation inaccuracies into the reading) then, you should make the burden resistor ten times greater i.e. 100 Ω. This levels up the playing field (so to speak).

**Worth a try but, take it carefully and increase the RMS current slowly**

Test the CT and 10 Ω burden resistor with 16.3 amps fed through the CT's aperture using 10 primary loops. Watch out for anything overheating as you raise the current up to 16.3 amps RMS.

Comment: @jyelton. thanks for the correction attempts but really, where you removed the comma I should have this phrase in parenthesis: *and prove that the core isn't introducing saturation inaccuracies into the reading*. Not sure about removing the semi-colon after the word greater (still thinking about that one) but, moving the position of the comma after then is altering my intended meaning <-- I was using "then" as an interjection so, the comma should be afterwards: https://prowritingaid.com/comma-before-or-after-then

Comment: @jyelton regarding this: "*make the burden resistor ten times greater; i.e. 100 Ω*", I'm reverting it to how I originally wrote it (without the semicolon) because that is regarded as correct Britlish! In the US, the correct way would be: *make the burden resistor ten times greater i.e., 100 Ω* <-- note the comma after i.e.

Comment: You're good, the parentheses make this far more clear! Thanks for the feedback.

Comment: It's good that you ain't pissy about this @JYelton

Comment: Not at all, I just aim to make things clear and readable and enjoy reading and learning from you.